Propiedad "mostrar solo valores de origen de fila". Tablas (campos), formularios e informes (controles). Access
Tengo entendido que esta propiedad permite elegir si se muestran en, un desplegable de cuadro combinado, o un cuadro de lista, las opciones escritas manualmente que están fuera del origen de la lista.
Pongo ejemplo. Campo Productos. "coche" "barco" "moto". El cuadro combinado despliega esas tres opciones. Si pongo la propiedad limitar a la lista en NO, puedo añadir manualmente otras opciones, tanto en el campo, como en los controles. No edito la lista, sólo escribo manualmente otros valores.
Según dice la documentación de  microsoft sobre la propiedad "mostrar solo valores...", dejo enlace debajo, la opción SI no me dejaría ver en el desplegable nada más que Coche, barco, moto. Si elijo NO, tendría que ver en el desplegable las palabras que introduje manualmente. Cosa que nunca pasa. Siempre veo sólo la lista de origen.
Haga lo que haga, elija el origen lista de valores o campo de una tabla, no consigo que haya diferencias entre SI/NO. Por lo que no sé lo que realmente hace esta propiedad. ¿Hace algo realmente?, necesito un contexto muy específico, tocar otra propiedad, no lo sé.
Ayuda de Microsoft
